# Spray-can NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spray

I'm new to spray, i can't get it to work... :/

My build.sbt:

```
val apacheDeps = Seq(
  "commons-validator" % "commons-validator" % "1.4.1"
)

val sprayAndAkkaDeps = {
  val sprayV = "1.3.3"
  Seq(
    "io.spray"            %%  "spray-can"     % sprayV,
    "io.spray"            %%  "spray-routing" % sprayV,
    "io.spray"            %%  "spray-testkit" % sprayV  % "test",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.9"
  )
}

name := "myApp"
version := "1.0.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.8.1",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.3",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.4.0",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.6.1" % "test",
  "com.netaporter" %% "scala-uri" % "0.4.7"
) ++ apacheDeps ++ sprayAndAkkaDeps

Revolver.settings
```

My main object:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.io.IO
import akka.pattern.ask
import spray.can.Http
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Main extends App {

  implicit val timeout = new Timeout(5.seconds)

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("acontextGen")

  val listener = system.actorOf(Props[listeners.MyHttpListener], "httpListener")

  IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(listener, interface = "localhost", port = 7777)

}
```

My listener:

```
package listeners

import spray.routing._

class MyHttpListener extends HttpServiceActor {

  def receive = runRoute {

    path("hi") {
      get {
        complete("hello")
      }
    }

  }

}
```

And the problem. When i run i get this output and server doesn't start on 7777 port

```
> gen[ERROR] Uncaught error from thread [acontextGen-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[acontextGen]
gen[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shapeless/PrependAux$
gen[ERROR]      at spray.routing.directives.PathDirectives$class.pathPrefix(PathDirectives.scala:40)
gen[ERROR]      at spray.routing.HttpServiceActor.pathPrefix(HttpService.scala:96)
gen[ERROR]      at spray.routing.directives.PathDirectives$class.path(PathDirectives.scala:33)
gen[ERROR]      at spray.routing.HttpServiceActor.path(HttpService.scala:96)
gen[ERROR]      at listeners.MyHttpListener.receive(MyHttpListener.scala:9)
gen[ERROR]      at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:558)
gen[ERROR]      at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
gen[ERROR]      at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
gen[ERROR]      at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
gen[ERROR]      at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:279)
gen [ERROR] [06/19/2015 18:41:00.089] [acontextGen-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [ActorSystem(acontextGen)] Uncaught error from thread [acontextGen-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
gen java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shapeless/PrependAux$
gen     at spray.routing.directives.PathDirectives$class.pathPrefix(PathDirectives.scala:40)
gen     at spray.routing.HttpServiceActor.pathPrefix(HttpService.scala:96)
gen     at spray.routing.directives.PathDirectives$class.path(PathDirectives.scala:33)
gen     at spray.routing.HttpServiceActor.path(HttpService.scala:96)
gen     at listeners.MyHttpListener.receive(MyHttpListener.scala:9)
gen     at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:558)
gen     at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
gen     at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
gen     at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
gen     at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:279)
gen     at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
gen     at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)
gen     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
gen     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1253)
gen     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1346)
gen     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
gen     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
gen Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: shapeless.PrependAux$
gen     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
gen     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
gen     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
gen     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
gen     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
gen     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
gen     ... 17 more
gen 
gen[ERROR]      at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
gen[ERROR]      at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)
gen[ERROR]      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
gen[ERROR]      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1253)
gen[ERROR]      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1346)
gen[ERROR]      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
gen[ERROR]      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
gen[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: shapeless.PrependAux$
gen[ERROR]      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
gen[ERROR]      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
gen[ERROR]      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
gen[ERROR]      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
gen[ERROR]      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
gen[ERROR]      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
gen[ERROR]      ... 17 more
gen ... finished with exit code 255
```

Could you explain me what am i doing wrong?
I have followed this example: https://github.com/spray/spray-template/tree/on_spray-can_1.3 which works although

```
> show externalDependencyClasspath
[info] List(Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.6.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.mongodb/casbah-commons_2.11/jars/casbah-commons_2.11-2.8.1.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.nscala-time/nscala-time_2.11/jars/nscala-time_2.11-1.0.0.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/jars/mongo-java-driver-2.13.1.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.mongodb/casbah-core_2.11/jars/casbah-core_2.11-2.8.1.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.mongodb/casbah-query_2.11/jars/casbah-query_2.11-2.8.1.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.mongodb/casbah-gridfs_2.11/jars/casbah-gridfs_2.11-2.8.1.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/jars/logback-core-1.1.2.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.11/bundles/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11/jars/play-json_2.11-2.4.0.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-iteratees_2.11/jars/play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-stm/scala-stm_2.11/jars/scala-stm_2.11-0.7.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.3.0.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-functional_2.11/jars/play-functional_2.11-2.4.0.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-datacommons_2.11/jars/play-datacommons_2.11-2.4.0.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/joda-time/joda-time/jars/joda-time-2.7.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.joda/joda-convert/jars/joda-convert-1.7.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.11.6.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/bundles/jackson-core-2.5.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/bundles/jackson-annotations-2.5.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/bundles/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.5.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/bundles/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.5.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.netaporter/scala-uri_2.11/jars/scala-uri_2.11-0.4.7.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.parboiled/parboiled_2.11/jars/parboiled_2.11-2.0.1.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/commons-validator/commons-validator/jars/commons-validator-1.4.1.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.2.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/commons-digester/commons-digester/jars/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-can_2.11/bundles/spray-can_2.11-1.3.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-io_2.11/bundles/spray-io_2.11-1.3.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-util_2.11/bundles/spray-util_2.11-1.3.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-http_2.11/bundles/spray-http_2.11-1.3.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.parboiled/parboiled-scala_2.11/jars/parboiled-scala_2.11-1.1.7.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.parboiled/parboiled-core/jars/parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-routing-shapeless2_2.11/bundles/spray-routing-shapeless2_2.11-1.3.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-httpx_2.11/bundles/spray-httpx_2.11-1.3.3.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/org.jvnet.mimepull/mimepull/jars/mimepull-1.9.5.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.11/bundles/shapeless_2.11-2.1.0.jar), Attributed(/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/jars/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar))
```

Comment: One of your other dependencies probably depends on a version of shapeless incompatible with spray-routing. Can you show the output of running `show externalDependencyClasspath` in sbt? Even better would be the output of using `sbt-dependency-graph`. Assuming that something requires shapeless 2, you could also directly try using `spray-routing-shapeless2` instead of `spray-routing`.

Comment: I trie'd to run sbt-dependency-graph --force but it takes much time so i can show first command output (attached to the end of question post)

Comment: Replacing spray-routing with spray-routing-shapeless2 helped me! Thanks a lot! I don't like use things that i don't understand but it's ok for now :)

Comment: Glad it worked. `dependencyGraph` doesn't work for too big projects. `depedencyTree` should still work in those cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that shapeless 1.x and shapeless 2.x are not compatible. However, if you mix dependencies that depend on both versions of shapeless sbt's dependency manager will by default just evict the older version. That's what happened here:

```
> dependencyTree
myapp:myapp_2.11:1.0.0 [S]
  +-com.netaporter:scala-uri_2.11:0.4.7 [S]
  | +-org.parboiled:parboiled_2.11:2.0.1 [S]
  |   +-com.chuusai:shapeless_2.11:2.0.0 [S]
  |
  +-io.spray:spray-routing_2.11:1.3.3 [S]
  | +-com.chuusai:shapeless_2.11:1.2.4 (evicted by: 2.0.0)
  | +-io.spray:spray-http_2.11:1.3.3 [S]
  | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.11:1.3.3 [S]
  | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:1.1.7 [S]
  | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.7
  | | ...
```

`spray-routing` still depends on `shapeless` 1.x while `scala-uri` relies on `parboiled2` which depends on `shapeless` 2.x.

The solution is to use the `spray-routing-shapeless2` module which was built specifically to help with problems like this.