# SBT project results in NoClassDefFoundError at runtime

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, repository, spray

I was playing with dependencies and having issues.  I wanted to switch from spray-json to spray-json-shapeless.  The code will compile and IntelliJ is not complaining about any errors but I continuously get a runtime error for `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shapeless/PrependAux$`.  I ended up backing up the existing project and then doing a `git reset --hard` to just get it to run again.  That didn't work and I still the same runtime error.  I have tried clearing out target directories, maven/ivy/sbt caches, and upgrading SBT.  Maybe I didn't do it in the right order.  I did read about the spray/shapeless issues but I think my versioning is correct.  I know that last time I checked into git everything was working so something else is messed up. I could post build.sbt but I 100% promise you this version of the code was running yesterday.

error:

```
[ERROR] [05/27/2016 17:35:36.732] [xxx-xxxx-service-system-
akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://xxx-xxxx-service-system/user/xxx-xxxx-service] null
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:166)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:596)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.instantiate(Reflect.scala:66)
    at akka.actor.ArgsReflectConstructor.produce(Props.scala:352)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:252)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:552)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
    ... 9 more
**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shapeless/PrependAux$**
    at spray.routing.directives.PathDirectives$class.pathPrefix(PathDirectives.scala:40)
    at com.tacos.arch.rest.service.MHttpServiceActor.pathPrefix(MHttpServiceActor.scala:10)
    at com.tacos.arch.rest.MRoutingDirectives$class.terminalPath(MRoutingDirectives.scala:11)
    at com.tacos.arch.rest.service.MHttpServiceActor.terminalPath(MHttpServiceActor.scala:10)
    at com.tacos.arch.PricingService$class.sayHi(PricingService.scala:139)
    at com.tacos.arch.PricingService$class.$init$(PricingService.scala:188)
    at com.tacos.arch.PricingActor.<init>(PricingActor.scala:5)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: shapeless.PrependAux$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Is this with `sbt ~compile` ? Have you tried `sbt clean` or `sbt clean-files`

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry.  I have tried clean and clean-files.  It compiles and builds fine.  This is a runtime issue.

Comment: Perhaps you updated shapeless? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941202/spray-can-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: This code is totally unchanged.  I did see that post before and did try using `spray-routing-shapeless2`.

Comment: ok - I just literally played with it for 2 hours.  I made a new package, decided I didn't want it, deleted it.  And now the silly thing works.

Comment: I feel you pain, have been there! (Would upvote again.) :(